# Magento: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: magento-1.9, permissions, local.xml

I have Configured Magento With Valid Credentials. But, it shows `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`
.
I have Cleared Cache(Deleted var Folder).

Cross Checked `app/etc/local.xml`

Gave 777 Permission to root folder.

I Checked by Renamed/Deleted `app/etc/local.xml` still it shows the same Error.

Comment: is this root db details correct ? check if there is any other backup local.xml exist in etc folder and delete if exist.

Comment: Yeah Thanks @PankajPareek. It worked. But Why it is taking instead `local.xml`

Comment: Magento loads all the xml file in etc folder and then merge the node. If we need to take backup then use backup string with extension name instead of file name.

Comment: @PankajPareek. Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved my issue.

I had other backup `local.xml` file. When i removed this it's worked fine.

Credits @Pankaj Pareek